# Set associative array key value from database ID column

Tags: php

I have a database table for products. Each product has a unique ID.

For my project I am adding items to a cart and want to store the items in an associative array and set the key value from the 'ProductID' column from the database.

Problem I am getting is that the result array generates "automatic" key values and not the values from the ID column as wanted.

```
ID         ProductName       Price
2be        Prod1             21.54
3sq        Prod2             64.61
5gh        Prod3             34.44
```

What I'm going for is:

```
  2be => [ProductName],[Price]
```

This is some of the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['productID']) && $_POST['productID'] != ""){
        $product = $_POST['productID'];

        $result_product = GetSpecificProduct($product);

        $product_id = $result_product['ProductID'];
        $product_name = $result_product['ProductName'];
        $product_price = $result_product['Price'];
        $product_spec = $result_product['Specifications'];
        $product_co = $result_product['CO'];
        $product_catID = $result_product['CatID'];
        $product_cat_name = $result_product['Name'];


        $cart_array = array(
            $result_product["ProductID"]=>array(
                'ProductID'=>$product_id,
                'ProductName'=>$product_name,
                'Price'=>$product_price,
                'Specifications'=>$product_spec,
                'CO'=>$product_co,
                'CatID'=>$product_catID,
                'Name'=>$product_cat_name,
                'Quantity'=>1
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: One thing to look at from the style point of view - you have a lot of variables containing values from one array and then just assign them to another array.  Instead of creating variables like `$product_id` - just assign the value directly `'ProductID'=>$result_product['ProductID'],`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really all you need:

```
$result_product = GetSpecificProduct($product);
$cart_array[$result_product["ProductID"]] = $result_product;
```

Or the way you were doing it:

```
    $cart_array[$result_product["ProductID"]] = array(
            'ProductID'=>$product_id,
            'ProductName'=>$product_name,
            'Price'=>$product_price,
            'Specifications'=>$product_spec,
            'CO'=>$product_co,
            'CatID'=>$product_catID,
            'Name'=>$product_cat_name,
            'Quantity'=>1
        )
    );
```